# How to use the eclipse network connection page in your RCP application?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I want to use the eclipse Network Connections page in my RCP application.

Is there a jar or plug-in kind of think, using which if I just call some method at my handler that window would pop up, without really creating the preference window? I followed [this](http://blog.vogella.com/2009/12/08/eclipse-rcp-proxy-preference/) link, but its talking about the network connection, but not how they brought the there mentioned window!

I am very new in this field, so sorry for any silly mistake in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This preference page has id `org.eclipse.ui.net.NetPreferences` you can show just that preference page using:

```java
Shell shell = .... get current shell

String id = "org.eclipse.ui.net.NetPreferences";

PreferenceDialog dialog 
   = PreferencesUtil.createPreferenceDialogOn(shell, id, new String[] {id}, null);

dialog.open();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I do believe it will work, the minor problem that I am facing after applying this code snippet is: 
" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet. " can you focus on the possible cause please?

Comment: This code will only work in a plugin installed in a running Eclipse (or RCP). It sounds like you are trying to use it in a plain Java app or a headless RCP - you can't do that.